# How can I display different success / error PHP messages using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

If I keep email and/or secret code fields blank and try to submit form, it gives me client side error message to fill required data in input box.

Once I submit form after entering correct email and secret code on form page, it inserts data in database table and gives me success message.

But if I submit form after entering incorrect email and/or secret code on form page, it doesn't inserts data in database table due to server side validation script I have written but still gives me success message instead of giving specific error message for incorrect email and/or secret code.

What do I need to do to display specific error messages those I am getting from server side page for incorrect data?

***Client Side Page (contact.js)***

```
$(function() {
    $("#MyFormName input).jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
        // something to have when submit produces an error ?
        // Not decided if I need it yet
    },
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
        // get values from FORM
        var emailid = $("input#emailid").val();
        var secretcode = $("input#secretcode").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "./contact_p.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                emailid: emailid,
                secretcode: secretcode
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
                // Success message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append("<strong>Success Message will come here.</strong>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append('</div>');

                //clear all fields
                $('#FormPRegister').trigger("reset");
            },
            error: function() {
                // Fail message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + " Error Message will come here!");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                //clear all fields
                $('#FormPRegister').trigger("reset");
            },
        })
    },
    filter: function() {
        return $(this).is(":visible");
    },
});

$("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab("show");
});
});

/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#r_name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

***Server Side page (contact_p.php)***

```
if( empty($str_emailid) )
{
    echo "No Email ID entered!";
    return false;
}
if( empty($str_secretcode) || $_SESSION['image_secret_code'] != $str_secretcode )
{
    echo "Invalid Secret Code!";
    return false;
}

$str_insert = "INSERT INTO t_contact (emailid,idate,ipaddress) VALUES('".$str_emailid."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."','".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."')";
RunQuery($str_insert);

return true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I am posting my entire working script in PHP, AJAX, JSON. I am sure other people will have different type of working scripts for contact form page but this is working fine for me.

I got help of many guys from here to make it working. So this is effort of all of them and I really want to thank them for their help. So I thought that I should post entire script here so it can be useful to other persons like me too.

NOTE#1 : **alert(data);** will help to alert JSON array response with status and message

NOTE#2: I am not using any ready made captacha script

**contact.php**

```
<form name="FormPRegister" id="FormPRegister" novalidate>
.
.
other form fields will come here
.
.
<div class="control-group form-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <label>Email Address:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="r_email" name="r_email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group form-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <label>Secret Code:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="r_secretcode" name="r_secretcode" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter secret code from given image."><span class="input-group-addon input-group-addon-no-padding"><img src="./includes/get_unique_image.php" border="0"></span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="success"></div>
<!-- For success/fail messages -->
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="9">Send Message</button>
</form>
```

**contact.js**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "./contact_p.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
    emailid: emailid,
    secretcode: secretcode
},
cache: false,

success: function(data) 
{
//alert(data);
var $responseText=JSON.parse(data);
if($responseText.staus == 'SUC')
{
    // Success message
    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
    .append("</button>");
    $('#success > .alert-success').append("<strong> " + $responseText.message + " </strong>");
    $('#success > .alert-success').append('</div>');

    //clear all fields
    $('#FormPRegister').trigger("reset");
}

else if($responseText.status == 'ERR')
{
    // Fail message
    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
    .append("</button>");
    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong> " + $responseText.message + " ");
    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
}
},
})
```

**contact_p.php**

```
.
.
other script will come here as per requirements
.
.
if( empty($_POST["r_email"]) )
{
    $response['status']='ERR';
    $response['message']= "Invalid Email ID!";
    echo json_encode($response); 
    return;
}
if( empty($_POST["r_secretcode"]) || $_SESSION['image_secret_code'] != $_POST["r_secretcode"] )
{
    $response['status']='ERR';
    $response['message']= "Invalid Secrete Code!";
    echo json_encode($response);
    return;
}
.
.
other script will come here as per requirements
.
.
if( Invalid data then do this )
{
    $response['status']='ERR';
    $response['message']= "Invalid Secrete Code!";
    echo json_encode($response);
    return;
}
if( Valid data then do this )
{
    $response['status']='SUC';
    $response['message']= "Inquiry submitted successfully";
    echo json_encode($response);
    return;
}
.
.
other script will come here as per requirements
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use json format for efficient in php like following -

```
if( empty($str_emailid) )
{
    $response['status']='ERR';
    $response['message']= "No Email ID entered!";
    return json_encode($response);
}
if( empty($str_secretcode) || $_SESSION['image_secret_code'] !=        $str_secretcode )
{
    $response['status']='ERR';
    $response['message']= "Invalid Secrete Code!";
    return json_encode($response);
}
$str_insert = "INSERT INTO t_contact (emailid,idate,ipaddress) VALUES('".$str_emailid."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."','".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."')";
RunQuery($str_insert);
$response['status']='OK';
$response['message']='Inserted successfully';
return json_encode($response);
```

in jquery side in success

```
 success: function(data) {
            // Success message
             $responsetext=JSON.parse(data);
             if($responseText.status=='OK')
             {
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                .append("<strong>Success Message will come here.</strong>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                .append('</div>');

                //clear all fields
                $('#FormPRegister').trigger("reset");
             }
            else if($responseText.status=='ERR')
           {
                // do your stuff with your error 
            }

        },
```

hope this is pretty helpful to you?

Comment: Ty for your detailed answer. But now it doesn't allow me to submit form after making changes you suggested.

Comment: look carefully and check your spellings to... i am using same format since 1 year .... in jquery just copy the success function and paste in your code,,, look at console to ensure syntax error.... with out this how can you down vote hmmm... i just edit my code for your easiness .... and response me

Comment: Sorry but I have not down vote your answer... and I will check syntax and other things like you suggested.

Comment: just copy and paste success method ... if there is any error in console please inform me

Comment: I have used same piece of code you have written for success method. Form is submitted and data are successfully inserted into database. But I am not getting any success or error message on page.

Comment: ok just below success function write alert(data); and send the text to me appears in alert box

Comment: i mean just above $responsetext=JSON.parse(data); write alert(data);

Comment: Sorry but not getting any alert box after submission. What should I do now? I am sure that I am not far away to resolve this issue.

Comment: you need to write "alert(data)" then this will alert something just before "$responsetext=JSON.parse(data);" this piece of code

Comment: ok, alert box is opened now. But no message is displaying except 'OK' button in alert box..

Comment: can you please help me out?   alert box is opened now. But no message is displaying except 'OK' button in alert box. Now what should I do?

Comment: Can you please clarify your last message.

Comment: i am just leaving  right now...... you can post php code and ajax success function's code in comment ..... so that i can reply you on the basis of comment... and you will get response only after 4hrs

Comment: hey ... are you done with your problem, if not please inform me

Comment: No, problem is still unresolved. I will put code for your review in my question, is that ok with you? I guess it will uneasy to read large piece of code in comment. Please let me know.

Comment: its ok you can post in my email..... jjoshiganeshraj@gmail.com.... i will respond on it

Answer (score 0):

That is not your "server side page" Since you're giving returns, this is a method. Depending on your set up, you should probably return information in a JSON object so javascript can easily access your information, maybe provide the name of the object.

{errors:[email:"no Email entered"]}

etc. Whilst doing this, if you follow standards, you should probably return a 400 header as well (goes anywhere in the code when things go wrong).

```
header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad-Request', true, 400);
```

this should cause the error function to be triggered.

Avoid just echoing strings, allthough it should work in your case when you also set this header.

You should probably also tag jQuery in your question since this is jQuery related.

Edit:

Forgot one thing, to actually make use of the response from the server implement the following:

Was this:

```
    error: function() {
```

should be

```
    error: function(response, status, xhr) {
```

For more info just look at the jquery docs, same goes for success messages. you can check the response there in the same manner.

If you just echo a string, the response should contain the error message object. A Json object would allow more information to be returned for example.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Ty for your reply. Is there any tutorial or guide or help where I can study and implement what you have suggested in your answer. It will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Not sure, but I guess you could start of with basic jQuery and php Tutorials, google should help you find some.

It takes practice I guess.

Answer (score 0):

That's how ajax works. Your php code is fine that's why your ajax execute `success` function. `error` will only execute if your request failed.

In this case you need to handle your error message in `success` function.

Try this :

PHP code :

```
if( empty($str_emailid) )
{
    $arr = array("msg"=>"No Email ID entered!","status"=>400);

} else if( empty($str_secretcode) || $_SESSION['image_secret_code'] != $str_secretcode )
{

    $arr = array("msg"=>"Invalid Secret Code!","status"=>400);
} else {

$str_insert = "INSERT INTO t_contact (emailid,idate,ipaddress) VALUES('".$str_emailid."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."','".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."')";
RunQuery($str_insert);

$arr = array("msg"=>"Success","status"=>200);
}

  echo json_encode($arr); 
  exit;
```

And your success function in ajax :

```
success: function(res) {
                if(res.status == 400) {
                  //error message
                } else {
                  //success message
                }
            }
```

Comment: Doesn't the status 400 trigger the error? I don't use jquery anymore but I thought it would.

Comment: No, not in my case.I just pass status to check if it's error message or success message. i'm not sending HTTP response code.

Comment: Ah didn't look at your php. That would work as well yes.

Comment: I guess someone downvoted it for now following stardards or something. I didn't downvote it since whilst learning this should be ok.